# Conditional JQuery form that hides or displays a DIV based on the selection?

Tags: jquery, css, html, drop-down-menu

I have a form with a couple dropdown menus, but I'm trying to get a DIV that displays based on your selection. For example:

If the user chooses "Option 1" from the dropdown, is sends it to JQuery which then comes back to HTML and tells it to display "DIV 1". And the same if "Option 2" is chosen, then "DIV 2" is displayed and then "DIV 1" is hidden.

If this is possible, any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks alot!

Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/2XV7w/5/

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you start:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>StackOverflow</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <select name="">
          <option id="value1" value="">Value 1</option>
          <option id="value2" value="">Value 2</option>
      </select>

        <div id="content1">Conteudo 1</div>
        <div id="content2">Conteudo 2</div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#content1').hide();
            $('#content2').hide();

            $('#value1').select(function(){
                $('#content1').show();    
            });

            $('#value2').select(function(){
                $('#content2').show();    
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I forgot to add jquery script.